# LAZ reprojection to UTM

Tags: fusion

In FUSION you can reproject the final output, for example in case of `ASCII` to `DTM`, one can use:

```
ASCII2DTM canopy.dtm m m 1 10 2 2 canopy_southern.asc
```

So my question is how can I reproject a LAZ file from `NAD83` to `WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_11N` in FUSION?